# PyCharm imported module shows red program works though

Tags: pycharm

Basically what the title says. PyCharm is saying that my module can't be found, but the program runs just fine with it. The module is in the same directory. (See screenshot below)

[red_module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDEx.jpg)

Comment: What does the tooltip say when you hover over the section underlined in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running your files in a different way to what PyCharm expects. It expects you to be in the `python_projects` folder, running a command like `python3 -m word_games.anagrams`, though you are probably doing something like `python3 word_games.py` from the `word_games` folder.

To fix this, either open the `word_games` folder as a project in PyCharm rather than `python_projects`, or change your code so it can be run in the way PyCharm expects by changing the import to `import word_games.load_dictionary as load_dictionary`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense.